# Как ограничить вводимые данные в input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения, input, try-catch

Есть очень простой калькулятор написанный на Python

```
num1 = input("Enter a number: ") 
num2 = input("Enter another number: ")
action = input("Please enter your operand: ")
reusultPlus = float(num1) + float(num2)
resultMinus = float(num1) - float(num2)
resultMultiply = float(num1) * float(num2)
resultDivide = float(num1) / float(num2)

def calculator(action, reusultPlus, resultMinus, resultMultiply, resultDivide):
    if action == "+":
        print(reusultPlus)
    elif action == "-":
        print(resultMinus)
    elif action == "*":
        print(resultMultiply)
    elif action == "/":
        print(resultDivide)

calculator(action, reusultPlus, resultMinus, resultMultiply, resultDivide)
```

Есть следующий вопрос:

- Как я могу ограничить набор символов которые я могу вводить в input? (допустим я хочу что бы юзеры могли вводить только цифры в инпут num1 / num2), а так же например ограничить ввод операндов в action инпут (разрешить ввод только + - / *)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
a = ''

while not a.isnumeric():
    if a != '':
        print(f'{a} is not a number')
    a = input("Enter a number: ")
```

Answer (score 2):

С регулярками попроще:

```
import re

def func(exp, mes, arg=''):
    while not re.match(exp, arg):
        arg = input(mes)
    return arg

num1 = func(r'^\d+$', 'Enter first number: ')
act  = func(r'^[-+*/]$', 'Enter operator: ')
num2 = func(r'^\d+$', 'Enter second number: ')

result = eval(num1 + act + num2)
print(f'{num1} {act} {num2} = {result}')
```

Результат:

```
 in: Enter first number: 10
 in: Enter operator: /
 in: Enter second number: 2
out: 10 / 2 = 5.0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
num1 = input("Enter a number: ") 
num2 = input("Enter another number: ")
action = input("Please enter your operand: ")

try:
    reusultPlus = float(num1) + float(num2)
    resultMinus = float(num1) - float(num2)
    resultMultiply = float(num1) * float(num2)
    resultDivide = float(num1) / float(num2)

    # action check
    if action not in ["+", "-", "*", "/"]:
        raise ValueError

except ValueError:
    print('Bad data passed.')
    exit()

def calculator(action, reusultPlus, resultMinus, resultMultiply, resultDivide):
    if action == "+":
        print(reusultPlus)
    elif action == "-":
        print(resultMinus)
    elif action == "*":
        print(resultMultiply)
    elif action == "/":
        print(resultDivide)

calculator(action, reusultPlus, resultMinus, resultMultiply, resultDivide)
```

Да, можно и даже нужно использовать операторы `try-except`. Только скорее вот так.

Answer (score -2):

Для конкретно проверки цифр try-except для вашего кода:

```
def calc():
 
      num1 = input("Enter a number: ")
      num2 = input("Enter another number: ")
      action = input("Please enter your operand: ")
      try:  
        reusultPlus = float(num1) + float(num2)
        resultMinus = float(num1) - float(num2)
        resultMultiply = float(num1) * float(num2)
        resultDivide = float(num1) / float(num2)
      except ValueError:
        print("Вводите только цифры!!!")  
        calc()
        exit()


      def calculator(action, reusultPlus, resultMinus,
                       resultMultiply, resultDivide):
            if action == "+":
                print(reusultPlus)
            elif action == "-":
                print(resultMinus)
            elif action == "*":
                print(resultMultiply)
            elif action == "/":
                print(resultDivide)

        calculator(action, reusultPlus, resultMinus,
                   resultMultiply, resultDivide)
```

Для проверки операндов можно просто через цикл сравнивать его со списком операндов.

Comment: Вы в блок `try` запихнули весь код. А еще исправьте, пожалуйста, форматирование кода

Comment: ValueError в коде может возникнуть только в одном месте, так что разницы нет. Я не понял в чем ошибка форматирования?

Comment: `ValueError в коде может возникнуть только в одном месте` и при этом вы засовываете весь код в блок, так еще и функцию

Comment: @icYFTL Работоспособно в обоих случаях, но для Вас специально переместил сделал try-except только на часть

Comment: не только для меня.

Comment: @icYFTL Хорошо, не только для Вас.))

Comment: Зачем все засовывать в одну `calc()`?

Comment: @icYFTL незачем, но в python нет task main и т.п., так что это типа task main. + засчет этого программа не закрывается, а заново начинает работать.

Comment: Да ну хоспаде. Зачем `JS` приплели? `JS` помойка. Если не хотите, дабы скрипт завершался, то засуньте это в цикл бесконечный, а не городите рекурсии

Comment: Читал тему про js и опечатался - я имел виду python. Я не виноват, что Вы не любите рекурсии - мне с  ними удобнее